# jQuery not running with my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jQuery, so I need some help. I downloaded jQuery latest version from jquery.com.

I saved this  as a text file as `jquery.js`. Then I keep my html code & `jquery.js` in the same folder.

When I run my code my jQuery code function doesn't work, but when I used jQuery from Google in my code it  works very good

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

So please help me to get out my problem.

My  code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <script src="javascript/jquerymin.js"></script>
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $("p").hide("slow",function(){
                        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Hide</button>
        <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Press `F12` on your browser, select console, run the page and see what error is being thrown

Comment: Have you checked for errors in your console??

Comment: What's the name of the downloaded jQuery script file? Because you have 2 different names `jquery.js` and `jquerymin.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are working on windows, make sure file extension isn't hidden (which is default behavior for windows platform). if the extension is hidden then  Windows Operating system automatically adds extension to the file name you have given. for example, if you saved a file  as "jquerymin.js" then the file has actually been saved as "jquerymin.js.txt".

Comment: this is not, all things are ok in my code ,when I press the hide button the text is not hiding, it remain same after clicking the button, but when I use jquery google in my code the text is hide

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a `404` error when loading `javascript/jquerymin.js`.

> I save this as a text file as jquery.js. Then I keep my html code & jquery.js in same folder

This means that you have to change this:

```
<script src="javascript/jquerymin.js"></script>
```

into this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

---

Your application files will look like this:

```
site-root
├── index.html
└── jquery.js
```

Comment: I told that as an example "I save this as a text file as jquery.js. Then I keep my html code & jquery.js in same folder". I have make a folder name javascript & put the jquery file as <script src="javascript/jquerymin.js"> ,as like as code, so plz give me some idea.

Comment: @user222036 Open the page in Google Chrome, press `F12` and reload the page. Please tell me what errors do you see in the Developer Tool console...

Comment: when I press the hide button the text is not hiding, it remain same after clicking the button, but when I use jquery google in my code the text is hide

Comment: @user222036 have you checked for errors in console?? press F12 for that.

Comment: @user222036 Probably the jQuery script is not loaded in the page... Check the errors...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the file `jquerymin.js` inside the `javascript` folder.

Comment: yes I have put my jquerymin.js inside  javascript  folder but it is not working.

Comment: Check for the exact file name. It probably would be `jquery.min.js` with a period.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is a typo,

You have used `jquerymin.js` for including jquery

Usually the jquery min file come with below name

```
jquery.min.js
```

So,

Check your file name whether it is `jquerymin.js` or `jquery.min.js`

and as your `src="javascript/jquerymin.js"` it should be in a javascript folder inside root